# Java or Pig regex to strip out values from UserAgent string

Tags: java, regex, sed, hadoop, apache-pig

I need to strip out the third and subsequent values in the 'bracketed' component of the user agent string.

In order to get

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)

from

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; WinTSI 06.12.2009; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C)

I successfully use sed command

```
 sed 's/(\([^;]\+; [^;]\+\)[^)]*)/(\1)/'
```

I need to get the same result in [Apache Pig](http://pig.apache.org/) with a Java regex. 
Could anybody help me to re-write the above sed regular expression into Java?

Something like:

```
new = FOREACH userAgent GENERATE FLATTEN(EXTRACT(userAgent, 'JAVA REGEX?') as (term:chararray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Pig, but a look through the docs reveals a REPLACE function which wraps Java's `replaceAll()` method.  Try this:

```
REPLACE(userAgent, '\(([^;]+; [^;]+)[^)]*\)', '($1)')
```

That should match the whole parenthesized portion of the UserAgent string and replace its contents with just the first two semicolon-separated terms, just like your sed command does.

Comment: Thank you. But I was not able to get this `user_agent = FOREACH logs_filtered5 GENERATE FLATTEN(EXTRACT(userAgent,'\(([^;]+; [^;]+)[^)]*\)')) as (user_agent); ` working, I always got ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 36, column 74.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : "\'\\". Maybe this is something specific to PIG.

Comment: Maybe it expects backslashes to be escaped, as in Java string literals.  Try `'\\(([^;]+; [^;]+)[^)]*\\)'`

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't help `ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 36, column 80.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\'\\\\(([^;"`. Do you think that this can be related to PIG in interactive mode?

Comment: I don't know.  I have no experience with Pig, and I can't find any useful examples.  I do notice, however, that the code in your first comment doesn't call the REPLACE function.  Try replacing your EXTRACT call with what I posted.

Comment: The ERROR is exactly the same if I use REPLACE function (both with and without escaped backslashes). I have tried to run it in PIG MapReduce mode and it failed too, so it is not related to interactive mode.

Comment: The problem is [bug in PIG](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1581), the parser fails to treat semicolons correctly. When this is solved, your regex should work correctly.

Comment: That's a relief!  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can use Pig's ability to interpret unicode to get around this: \u003B maps to a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

In java if you use the Matcher class you can extract the capturing group. The following appears to do what you want, at least for the test case you provided.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; WinTSI 06.12.2009; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C)";
        //str = "aaa";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.*\\(.*?;.*?;).*\\)");
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(m.lookingAt());
        String group = m.group(1) + ")";
        System.out.println(group);
    }
 }
```

Hmm... I seemed to have answered the wrong question, since you were asking how to do this from 'PIG' not straight JAVA.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use your code in PIG to test it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As none of two suggested solutions seems to work in PIG I will post workaround which uses sed through stream:

```
user_agent_mangled = STREAM logs THROUGH `sed 's/(\\([^;]\\+; [^;]\\+\\)[^)]*)/(\\1)/'`;
```

This works well, however I would still prefer native PIG solution (using EXTRACT or REPLACE function).