# Useragent parsing with Hadoop

Tags: parsing, hadoop, user-agent

I'm looking for a library to help mi with extracting features from useragents to use with Hadoop (Pig or Hive). I'm interested mainly in mobile users.
I would like to be able to extract features like:

- OS version
- browser version
- screen size
- vendor name
- model name
- etc ... (features not explicitly given in useragent)

I was considering using projects like WURLF or OpenDDR, but they provide API that can be used within my Hadoop jobs which will not be very effective because the need of external server to serve that API.

If you are aware of such project please let me know, alternatively I'm looking for solution how to use WURLF or OpenDDR with Hadoop effectively.

Answer (score 2):

This package contains a UDF for Pig that may help.

https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use Hadoop and Wurfl is to use the streaming interface of Hadoop and write your mapper and reducer scripts in either PHP or Python. The mapper script would import the WURFL library and then you can lookup the device and emit the variables that you are looking for. The reducer should count appropriately.

A good tutorial about Hadoop, Python and the Streaming interface can be found at: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use RegEx, something like this: [Java or Pig regex to strip out values from UserAgent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236482/java-or-pig-regex-to-strip-out-values-from-useragent-string) might help.

If RegEx's don't help, then you may have to look at writing a custom UDF for Pig that can parse the user agent and output the info you need: http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual

I ended up writing a Hadoop streaming job in Python - the Python map program parsed the useragent string and output the variables, which were passed to the reducer. In pseudocode, it looked something like this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  result = mylog.parse (line)
  # mylog.parse() results a list/dictionary with the parsed line
  useragent = result['useragent']
  if ('indows' in useragent):
    os = "Windows"
  elif ('ndroid' in useragent):
    os = "Android"
  elif ('Linux' in useragent):
    os = "Linux"
  print os + "\t" + "1"
```